# Crash when replacing scene in Sprite kit

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

This is my code to replicate the scene:

```
SKScene * menu = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *transitionGameScene = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:2.0];
transitionGameScene.pausesIncomingScene = NO;
[self.view presentScene:menu transition:transitionGameScene];
return;
```

but does not work correctly, this code is called when I press the button to restart the level, some times the level restarts without any problems, other times it crashes, but the debugger does not give me any error, this is the screen xcode:

[image]

This is the NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);

```
0   Game                                0x000bdbe3 -[GameScene repleceScene] + 58
1   Game                                0x000bd875 __39-[GameScene sidebar:didTapItemAtIndex:]_block_invoke300 + 44
2   Game                                0x000d19f5 __47-[RNFrostedSidebar dismissAnimated:completion:]_block_invoke + 324
3   UIKit                               0x32510e6d <redacted> + 284
4   UIKit                               0x32510ab7 <redacted> + 178
5   UIKit                               0x325109cf <redacted> + 66
6   QuartzCore                          0x32166413 <redacted> + 234
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5960af <redacted> + 22
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3a5989a9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 268
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2fd1f5b1 <redacted> + 8
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2fd1de7d <redacted> + 1308
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2fc88471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2fc88253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13  GraphicsServices                    0x349c22eb GSEventRunModal + 138
14  UIKit                               0x3253d845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
15  Game                                0x000ad205 main + 116
16  libdyld.dylib                       0x3a5aaab7 <redacted> + 2
```

Can someone help me understand where is the problem??

Comment: First, set an Exception Breakpoint in your code. Second, post a full symbolicated crash log in your question. Finally, trying to teach you how to debug in Xcode is too big a topic for a question; look at some of the 2012 and 2013 WWDC videos if you don't know what to do or do an online search.

Comment: is your self.view a SKView object? If not, just do SKView *view = (SKView *)self.view; other code... [view presentScene:scene transition:transition]; hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My Code that works, looks exactly like your code except for two exceptions.

1. Trying removing transitionGameScene.pausesIncomingScene = NO;

or

1. Remove the return (can't see the rest of the code but i don't think you need this return if you are replacing the scene)

Try both of these and get back to me.